# Drop columns with more than 70% zeros

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to know if there is a command that drop columns that has more than 70% zeros or X% zeros. like:

```
     df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() < .7]
```

for NaN.

Thank you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change `df.isnull().mean()`  to `(df==0).mean()`:

```
df = df.loc[:, (df==0).mean() < .7]
```

---

Here's a demo:

```
df
Out: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  1  0
4  1  1  1  1  1
5  1  0  0  0  0
6  0  1  0  0  0
7  0  1  1  0  0
8  1  0  0  1  0
9  0  0  0  1  0

(df==0).mean()
Out: 
0    0.4
1    0.5
2    0.6
3    0.5
4    0.8
dtype: float64

df.loc[:, (df==0).mean() < .7]
Out: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  1  0
3  1  0  0  1
4  1  1  1  1
5  1  0  0  0
6  0  1  0  0
7  0  1  1  0
8  1  0  0  1
9  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: If it is a df that has mixed types, i.e. different types of NA; Is there a way of omitting columns the same way as here?